# ExtJS GridPanel ListFilter scrolling

Tags: javascript, extjs

I m working on a GridPanel which uses filters on its columns. These filters types are lists. So they are instances of ListFilter class.

My idea was to get a scrollbar on these listfilter items, cause sometimes I have many possible filter values and natively ExtJS doesn't come with a scrollbar for list typed filters. So, I've overridden the createMenu method of the ListFilter class to enable a scrollbar.

It looks like this now:

```
Ext.ux.grid.filter.ListFilter.prototype.createMenu = function (config) {
    var menuCfg = config.menuItems ? { items: config.menuItems } : {},
                menu;

    Ext.copyTo(menuCfg, config, "labelField,loadingText,loadOnShow,single,store,options");
    Ext.apply(menuCfg, {
        autoScroll: true
    });

    menu = Ext.create('Ext.ux.grid.menu.ListMenu', menuCfg);
    menu.self.xtype = "menu";
    menu.on('checkchange', this.onCheckChange, this);

    return menu;
};
```

This piece of code works well, a scrollbar is visible and can be used to scroll up/down through the list of filter values. But now, the problem is that this code disabled the natural scrolling behaviour using the mousewhell.

I'd like to get both working: the scrollbar and the mousewhell scrolling. I tried to set a fixed height to my menu but it doesn't fix anything.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Not an answer, yet it may be interesting to you. Here is another way how to filter the grid: [Ext Grid MultiSearch Plugin](http://extjs.eu/software/ext-grid-multisearch-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks, it looks cool but I think it is still menu-based so the same problem will appear

Comment: I'd rather put options in a combo that should be scrollable by default.